# How to get Resource Table from ASP.NET Web App?

Tags: asp.net, angular-translate

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that uses Web API and MVC. I have resource files in it to support multiple languages. I want to add a method in one of my Web API controllers that will return a resource table depending on a given language key.

Example:

```
// This should return all resources for Englsih (en)
api/translations?lang=en
```

I need this because I'm using [Angular Translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) and I want to use its [Asynchronous Loading](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading) feature.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Check the StackOverflow's help on asking questions first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.

Comment: What is this comment supposed to mean? :)

Comment: I'm sure you're smart and you will figure it out after reading of those help articles I have send you.